# Converting image to pixmap using ImageMagic libraries

Tags: c++, opengl, imagemagick, texture-mapping

My assignment is to get "images read into pixmaps which you will then convert to texture maps". So for the pixmap part only, hear me out and tell me if I have the right idea and if there's an easier way. Library docs I'm using: http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Documentation.html

Read in image:

```
Image myimage;
myimage.read( "myimage.gif" );
```

I think this is the pixmap I need to read 'image' into:

```
GLubyte pixmap[TextureSize][TextureSize][3];
```

So I think I need a loop that, for every 'pixmap' pixel index, assigns R,G,B values from the corresponding 'image' pixel indices. I'm thinking the loop body is like this:

```
pixmap[i][j][0] = myimage.pixelColor(i,j).redQuantum(void);
pixmap[i][j][1] = myimage.pixelColor(i,j).greenQuantum(void);
pixmap[i][j][2] = myimage.pixelColor(i,j).blueQuantum(void);
```

But I think the above functions return Quantums where I need GLubytes, so can anyone offer help here?

-- OR --

Perhaps I can take care of both the pixmap and texture map by using OpenIL (docs here: http://openil.sourceforge.net/tuts/tut_10/index.htm). Think I could simply call these in sequence?

```
ilutOglLoadImage(char *FileName);
ilutOglBindTexImage(ILvoid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the quantum values returned by `pixelColor(x,y)` to `ColorRGB` and you will get normalized (0.0,1.0) color values.

If you don't have to stick with Magick++ maybe you can try [OpenIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/), which can load and convert your image to OpenGL texture maps without too much hassle.

Comment: Actually, OpenIL does look pretty simple. Please take a look at my edit above. Is that all you would call? I'm going to try it out; if it works, this answer gets a big fat check.

Comment: "Just call ilutOglLoadImage with the name of the file you wish to load, and it will load the image directly into an OpenGL texture, then delete all unnecessary local data." (From the OpenIL manual) The returned GLuint is an OpenGL texture handle.

Comment: Is there something else besides ilut.h I have to #include? Because ilutRenderer(ILUT_OPENGL) works, but iluOglLoadImage "was not declared in this scope"

Comment: The proper image loading function is `GLuint ilutGLLoadImage(ILstring FileName)`, I think there is a typo in the tutorial.

Comment: You are right indeed. Unfortunately though I have to keep asking you questions :) If you could offer help on my segmentation fault with this function, please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8351115/1042847. Thanks.